# Como passo um id pela url usando CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Preciso passar o id de um produto pela url usando o método GET, em codeIgniter como  ficaria essa solução ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dependendo para que solução você deseja, você pode tratar diretamente pela própria URL.
Você tem que trazer o id por consulta e adicionar na sua referência. Ex:

```
<a href="<?= base_url('menu/produto') ?>?id=<?= $id ?>">Produto01</a>
```

E depois é só você recuperar o id na página aonde você fez a referencia:

```
idProduto = $_GET['id'];
```

Espero ter ajuda Eduarda...

Comment: Muito obrigada Yago Tomaz, ajudou sim!

Comment: @EduardaRosa, se a resposta do Yago tiver solucionado seu problema, a melhor forma de agradecer é marcando a resposta dele como aceita (clicando no "sinal de visto", ✓, logo abaixo da seta para baixo), veja essa página: [O que eu devo fazer se alguém responder minha pergunta?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), e [Por que é importante votar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote). Aproveite também para visitar a [página de boas-vindas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) do site.

Answer (score 1):

Seu arquivo de rotas deverá ter duas rotas: Uma para listar todos os produtos e outra para listar um produto especifico pelo Id do produto.

***routes.php***

```
//Lista produto
$route['produto'] = 'produto/index';

//Lista produto especifico
$route['produto/:id'] = 'produto/detalhe';
```

***Produto ( Controller da sua aplicação )***

```
<?php
class Produto extends CI_Controller {

        public function index()
        {
            $produtos[]  = [];
            $produtos[] = ['id' => 1, 'nome' => 'Televisão', 'descricao' => 'Televisao com 32 Polegadas']
            $produtos[] = ['id' => 2, 'nome' => 'Blusa', 'descricao' => 'Blusa verde tamanho M']
            $produtos[] = ['id' => 3, 'nome' => 'SmartPhone', 'descricao' => 'SmartPhone LG K10']

            $this->view('index', compact('$produtos');
        }
}
```

Perceba que na ***view*** você tem que passar a lista de produtos, para que possa ser listado em sua view

***index.php ( View da sua aplicação )***

```
<?php foreach($p as $produtos) { ?>
    <div class="container">
        <div>
            <?= $p->nome; ?>
        </div>
        <div>
            <?= $p->descricao; ?>
        </div>
        <a href="/produto/<?= $p->id; ?>">Detalhes do Produto</a>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

A grande sacada aqui é você usar o `href` ( um link ) concatenado com o **id** do seu produto para que ao clicar nesse link você possa ser redirecionado para o **rota** que você especificou via **GET**. Ai sim no criar um método detalhe em seu ***controller*** para tratar esse **id** do produto da melhor forma possível.

Comment: Obrigada por sua ajuda!